# Timing of portion of serial code increases when increasing the number of threads used to parallelize other portion of code

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to compare the timings of two algorithms ; one is run in serial and the other is run in parallel and I am using omp_get_wtime() to get the execution time of functions.
When the number of threads is increased to 2 then the execution time of serial part is getting doubled , even though the timing of parallel part is getting correctly reduced.
As the number of threads in parallel portion is increased the timing of serial portion is getting increased proportionally.

Sample code of portion that is being parallelized:

```
void constraints(int pop[], double gain[], double gammma[], double snr, int numberOfLinks, int chromosomes, int links,int (*cv)[])
{
    int i, j, k;
    double interference[chromosomes*links];
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,k) num_threads(4)
    for(i = 0; i < chromosomes; i++)
    {
        (*cv)[i] = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < links; j++)
        {
            interference[i * links + j] = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < links; k++)
            {
                if(k != j)
                {
                    interference[i * links + j] = interference[i * links + j] + pop[i * links + k] * gain[k * numberOfLinks + j];

                }
            }

            if (((gain[j * numberOfLinks + j]/(interference[i * links + j] + 1/snr)) < gammma[j]) && (pop[i * links + j] == 1))
            {

                (*cv)[i] = (*cv)[i] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could any one please let me know why this is happening.

Comment: The code that you posted is the parallel part. But, you didn't post the serial part that you speak of that is slowing down. I think you'll need to post the serial part as well. Without that, it's difficult to see how your parallel code is influencing the non-parallel section. Since this seems like a small enough amount, you might be able to post the entire program that can be compiled and run. It could be how you are measuring the timings as well. Also, posting some actual benchmark numbers would be helpful.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], present your specific measurement results (numbers instead of "increased" or "reduced"!), your compilation options and some general system specifications.